# discord bot -- node index.js problem -- "client is not defined"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js, bots

I've been working on a discord bot, but when I run `node main.js` it replies with this response:
(I have changed `index.js` with `main.js`, as that is what the file is called)

```
/Users/Liam/Desktop/Discordbot/main.js:7
client.once('ready', () => {
^

ReferenceError: client is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/Liam/Desktop/Discordbot/main.js:7:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47
```

This is my full code:

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("Online!");
});

client.login("TOKEN");
```

Comment: Is `discord.js` installed? And have you tried using Apostrophes?: `const Discord = require('discord.js')`

Comment: The complete code is not the one that was used when the error happend. ( Error says client.on line is on line 7, but in your posted code it is on line 5)

Answer (score 0):

I think you copied the wrong error, because when I tried to recreate this error it gave me different error, which has a simple solution.

client.login takes in a private discord token, I'm guessing you probably pasted the "TOKEN" string directly from a guide.

To create a bot token, follow the official docs at https://discordjs.guide/

After you created the token, you can do this:

```
const Discord = require("discord.js");

const client = new Discord.Client();

const token = 'ThePrivateTokenYouGenerated'

client.once("ready", () => {
    console.log("Online!");
});

client.login(token);
```